# How to show that $x^9-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q\Big(\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}5\right)\Big)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Show that $x^9-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q\Big(\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}5\right)\Big)$. Is it possible to solve it by the roots?

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the readability of your question

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha:=\sqrt[9]{3}$ and $\beta:=\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi\text{i}}{5}\right)$.  Denote by $\mathbb{K}$ the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$. Observe that
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=9$$
because $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x^9-3$, which is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by Eisenstein's Criterion.  Furthermore,
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=4$$
because $\beta$ is a root of the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, which is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  (Cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n(x)$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$; in particular, Eisenstein's Criterion can be used to prove irreducibility of $\Phi_p(x)$ for each prime natural number $p$.)  By the field version of Langrange's Theorem, $4$ and $9$ both divide $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]$.  Prove that $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]=4\cdot 9=36$, and use this to show that $$\big[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}(\beta)\big]=9\,.$$  What can you say about reducibility/irreducibility of $x^9-3$ of over $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$?